# matplotlib, add common horizontal lines at the x axis across multiple subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, line, horizontal-line

My plan is to have 4 `GridSpec(4,1)` gridspecs to create a 4x4 grid of subplots. I would like to add a horizontal line across the x-axes of each row of 4 subplots. I looked at matplotlib.lines.Line2D but couldn't really figure it out. Any suggestions? I'm trying to visually simplify the picture so it does not look like 16 separate graphs.

In the picture below I only have the first 2 gridspecs up, but I hope it offers a better idea of what I am hoping to achieve.

Thanks! Cheers

Code (the graph part):

```
#---the graph---
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')

gs1 = GridSpec(4,1)
gs1.update(left = 0.15, right = .3375 , wspace=0.02)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[3,0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[2,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[1,0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])



gs2 = GridSpec(4,1)
gs2.update(left = 0.3875, right = .575, wspace=.25)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs2[3,0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs2[2,0])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs2[1,0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs2[0,0])


show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the existing code?

Comment: @MrE for sure, i hope it's not too disorganized

Comment: Does this one help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840621/creating-matplotlib-graph-with-common-line-across-subplots-in-python/22845340#22845340, See the commented line: '#the above three lines to draw the line out of the box.'

Comment: @CTZhu I feel like the answer I am looking for is in there, but I can't seem to figure it out. based on the comments in the code I have been focusing on the `ll = plt.plot(xb,yb, '-b')
ll[0].set_clip_on(False) 
plt.axis([0,100,0,1.2])` section... however I am still pretty lost. Is that the right part to look at?

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  Please trim it down to a _minimal_ example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: My apologies. @tcaswell, I edited my original post and hope that is better

Comment: Can you hand draw a line to show where you want it to be? Because your y axes are of different scale.

Comment: @CTZhu I am hoping to apply four lines, one each at the X-axis (x = 0). Does that make sense, or should I draw one in?

Comment: For instance, at 0 between C8 and I1 in the bottom two graphs, and for each pair of graphs above those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the idea is to draw a line and allow the line to extend beyond the current view of axis, in this following example, I plot that line in red in order to see it better.

Also your 8 plots can be plotted in a nested loop, which will organize the code better and make this 'common line across subplot' easier to implement:

```
X=[1,3,4,5]
Y=[3,4,1,3]
L=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
f=plt.figure(figsize=(10,16), dpi=100)
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(4,1)
gs1.update(left = 0.15, right = .3375 , wspace=0.02)
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(4,1)
gs2.update(left = 0.3875, right = .575, wspace=.25)
sp1 = [plt.subplot(gs1[i,0]) for i in range(4)]
sp2 = [plt.subplot(gs2[i,0]) for i in range(4)]
for sp in [sp1, sp2]:
    for ax in sp:
        ax.bar(range(len(L)), X, 0.35, color='r')
        ax.bar(np.arange(len(L))+0.35, Y, 0.35)
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        if sp==sp1:
            ax.axis(list(ax.get_xlim())+list(ax.get_ylim())) #set the axis view limit
            ll=ax.plot((0,10), (0,0), '-r') #Let's plot it in red to show it better
            ll[0].set_clip_on(False) #Allow the line to extend beyond the axis view
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I don't think i'll be able to use the nested loop though because I want the xticklabels to only show for the bottom graphs.

Comment: If I were you, I will make the x ticks invisible for each subplot in the nested loop. Then make the x ticks separately for `sp1[-1]` and `sp2[-1]`.

Comment: how would I go about making the ticks separately for sp1[-1]?